# Unhandled error event with ionic serve

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

This is the error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
    at notFoundError (E:\IonicProjects\projectapp\ionic3\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:11:11)
    at verifyENOENT (E:\IonicProjects\projectapp\ionic3\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:46:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\IonicProjects\projectapp\ionic3\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:33:19)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
```

I don't get why this error is happening, I've been working on this project for a while and now **only with this project** is giving to me this error, I've tested with other project that I had made and it serves OK, I've read about ENOENT but I don't get why I have to add code on my project if **NEVER** I've changed libraries or something.

> Note: I'm runing a Windows 10

Comment: you fix this issue? If yes then kindly tell me how you fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by: 
1. clearing npm cache , run the following commands:

```
npm cache clean -f 
npm install npm -g
```

Then:
2. catch the exceptions on your code, it also thrown when there is un-catched exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing an npm i it could be that some library was updated and you are trying to update it and your environment is not ready for it.